# How to register OrientationEventListener to receive OrientationChange Notifications?

Tags: android, listener, screen-orientation

I am working on an android sdk and want to detect orientation changes without overriding OnConfigurationChanged api in Activity class as instance of activity is passed to my sdk.
OrientationChangedListener is described at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener

I want to know how can I register for OrientationChangedListener ?

I have looked around but examples of OrientationEventListener are not available.

Answer (score 0):

OrientationEventListener doesn't need to get registered in any register or addListener method of Activity.
You need to just a lambda instance of this class and then call *enable* method on it.

```
    val orientationEventListener = object : OrientationEventListener(context) {
        override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
            Log.d("OrientationEventListener", "Orientation is " + orientation)
            // Do your work on Orientation here
        }
    }

    if (orientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
        orientationEventListener.enable()
    }
```